# The language support for Java crashed 5 times on the last 3 minutes

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the Extension Pack for Java by Microsoft. I have a file called `main.java` that has the following code:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

But when I open the file in Visual Studio Code, I receive the infamous message "The Language Support for Java server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted.". I checked the logs and this is what in them:

```
{
  message: "Use the JDK from 'JAVA_HOME,PATH' as the initial default project JDK.",
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2022-08-18 15:10:02.759'
}
{
  message: 'Starting Java server with: c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\.vscode\\extensions\\redhat.java-1.9.0-win32-x64\\jre\\17.0.3-win32-x86_64\\bin\\java --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.fs=ALL-UNNAMED -Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1 -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 -Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product -Djava.import.generatesMetadataFilesAtProjectRoot=false -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -DwatchParentProcess=false -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -Xmx1G -Xms100m -javaagent:c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\.vscode\\extensions\\redhat.java-1.9.0-win32-x64\\lombok\\lombok-1.18.24.jar -jar c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\.vscode\\extensions\\redhat.java-1.9.0-win32-x64\\server\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar -configuration c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\redhat.java\\1.9.0\\config_ss_win -data c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\092e9f14627920ce78f64c2dbd9c572e\\redhat.java\\ss_ws',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2022-08-18 15:10:02.811'
}
{
  message: 'Starting Java server with: c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\.vscode\\extensions\\redhat.java-1.9.0-win32-x64\\jre\\17.0.3-win32-x86_64\\bin\\java --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.fs=ALL-UNNAMED -Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1 -Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4 -Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product -Djava.import.generatesMetadataFilesAtProjectRoot=false -Dfile.encoding=utf8 -DwatchParentProcess=false -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -Xmx1G -Xms100m -javaagent:c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\.vscode\\extensions\\redhat.java-1.9.0-win32-x64\\lombok\\lombok-1.18.24.jar -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\092e9f14627920ce78f64c2dbd9c572e\\redhat.java -jar c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\.vscode\\extensions\\redhat.java-1.9.0-win32-x64\\server\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar -configuration c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\globalStorage\\redhat.java\\1.9.0\\config_win -data c:\\Users\\Otávio Augusto Silva\\AppData\\Roaming\\Code\\User\\workspaceStorage\\092e9f14627920ce78f64c2dbd9c572e\\redhat.java\\jdt_ws',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2022-08-18 15:10:03.025'
}
{
  message: '*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message find class on InstrumentationImpl failed at e:\\jenkins\\tmp\\workspace\\build\\src\\src\\java.instrument\\share\\native\\libinstrument\\JPLISAgent.c line: 494\n' +
    '*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message instrumentation instance creation failed at e:\\jenkins\\tmp\\workspace\\build\\src\\src\\java.instrument\\share\\native\\libinstrument\\JPLISAgent.c line: 402\n',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2022-08-18 15:10:03.219'
}
{
  message: '*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message find class on InstrumentationImpl failed at e:\\jenkins\\tmp\\workspace\\build\\src\\src\\java.instrument\\share\\native\\libinstrument\\JPLISAgent.c line: 494\n' +
    '*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message instrumentation instance creation failed at e:\\jenkins\\tmp\\workspace\\build\\src\\src\\java.instrument\\share\\native\\libinstrument\\JPLISAgent.c line: 402\n',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2022-08-18 15:10:03.220'
}
{
  message: 'The Language Support for Java server crashed and will restart.',
  level: 'error',
  timestamp: '2022-08-18 15:10:03.222'
}
{
  message: '[Info  - 15:10:03] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2022-08-18 15:10:03.222'
}
{
  message: 'The Language Support for Java (Syntax Server) server crashed and will restart.',
  level: 'error',
  timestamp: '2022-08-18 15:10:03.223'
}
{
  message: '[Info  - 15:10:03] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2022-08-18 15:10:03.223'
}
```

How can I fix this and make the extensions work?

Answer (score 0):

Open the command palette with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace**.

Generally this will solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: Already tried that, tried reinstalling my JDK distribution, tried reinstalling Visual Studio Code (also deleted the .vscode folder) and still gives the same error :(

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/743) helps.